# How to initialize a list of hashset in java

Tags: java

I have a problem with initialize a list of hashset in java.

I tried `List<Set<Character>> list = new ArrayList<HashSet<Character>>();`

Then I got a error like: `incompatible types: ArrayList<HashSet<Character>> cannot be converted to List<Set<Character>>`.
However, `List<HashSet<Character>> list = new ArrayList<HashSet<Character>>();`works.

I am confused about it, because I can initialize a list of list by using: 
`List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

I thought the part in the lhs is just a interface or abstract class, so I thought `List<Set<T>>` would be ok...

Can someone explain it for me? Thanks!

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Thank you so much!